# Conditional replacement of numbers with regex

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

**Input:**

```
foobar10000foobar
foobar1000foobar
foobar100foobar
foobar10foobar
foobarfoobar
```

**Desired Output:**

```
foobar4foobar
foobar3foobar
foobar2foobar
foobar1foobar
foobar0foobar
```

In other words, the replacements should be the number of zeros contained in the matched numbers. The examples already contain all possible numbers: {**none**, 10, 100, 1000, 10000} .

Is there a way to do it with one regex statement?

(Side info: I want to implement a rule for the [RegReplace](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RegReplace) package for Sublime Text 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, as `re.sub` accepts a function as replacement. See [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

The replacement function takes a match object as parameter, and must return a string.

```
import re
texts = ['foobar10000foobar', 'foobar100foobar',
         'foobar1foobar', 'foobarfoobar']

def zeros_count(matchobj):
     return str(matchobj.group(0).count('0'))

def replace_zeros(text):
    return re.sub(r'\d+', zeros_count, text)

for text in texts:
    print(text, '-->', replace_zeros(text))

# foobar10000foobar --> foobar4foobar
# foobar100foobar --> foobar2foobar
# foobar1foobar --> foobar0foobar
# foobarfoobar --> foobarfoobar
```

Note that in the last case, there's no number to replace, so there is no logical place to insert a 0, as in your last desired output.